# CSS borders appearing and disappearing in MS Edge

Tags: html, css, microsoft-edge

My website code has an annoying problem. Whenever I view the page with Microsoft Edge and hover over a link, one of the borders turns and stays white until you hover over another link, which switches another border.

```css
body {
  font-family: Sans-Serif;
  background-color: blue;
}

.Overhead {
  background-color: red;
  background-image: url('cats.jpg');
}

.Title {
  margin: 5px;
}

.Active {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}

.Menu {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.Menu a {
  transition: .5s ease;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: grey;
  padding: 5px;
  float: left;
  width-max: 50px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.Menu a:visited {
  color: grey;
}

.Menu a:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}
```

```html
<div class="Overhead">
  <h1 class="Title">Title</h1>
  <div class="Menu">
    <a class="Active" style="background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);"><b>Home</b></a>
    <a><b>About</b></a>
    <a><b>Service</b></a>
    <a><b>Contact</b></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm looking for a way to change the CSS so the borders stop appearing. I tried to completely get rid of the border, but that didn't work. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: I dont see any border. What browser are you using. Can you attach an image?

Comment: There is no border here

Comment: Why are you adding border style and border color to your CSS if you don’t want the borders to show?

Comment: that is what I put.

Comment: What is really happening here ? i don't see no borders.

Comment: Hover over the menu links and then move your mouse away.  A white border is left.

Comment: The problem is in Microsoft Edge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you don't want a border, just do this
`border: 0px solid black;`
this will make it so there isn't a border, if you ever see one.

In your code up there, there isn't a border, so use this *if* you see your border.

Note: it could just be `border: 0px;`, but I haven't tried it.

```js
$('.a').mouseenter(function() {
  $(this).css("border", "0px")
  $(this).css("background-color", "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)");
  $(this).css("transition", "0.3s");
});
$('.a').mouseleave(function() {
  $(this).css("border", "0px")
  $(this).css("background-color", "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)");
  $(this).css("transition", "0.3s");
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Sans-Serif;
  background-color: blue;
}

.Overhead {
  background-color: red;
  background-image: url('cats.jpg');
}

.Title {
  margin: 5px;
}

.Active {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
}

.Menu {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.Menu a {
  transition: .5s ease;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: grey;
  padding: 5px;
  float: left;
  width-max: 50px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.Menu a:visited {
  color: grey;
}

.head {
  border: 0px solid black;
}
#service {
  margin-left: 0.4px;
}
#contact {
  margin-left: 0.35px;
}
  
}
#container {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="Overhead">
  <h1 class="Title">Title</h1>
  <div class="Menu">
  <div id="container">
    <a class="Active" style="background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);"><b>Home</b></a>
    <a id="about" class="a"><b class="head">About</b></a>
    <a id="service" class="a"><b class="head">Service</b></a>
    <a id="contact" class="a"><b class="head">Contact</b></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hover over the menu items and then move your mouse away. A white border is left.

Comment: nothing in chrome. I'll add in some jQuery to get rid of it in edge.

Comment: no, it has to be how microsoft edge processes it. Just try this in edge again.

Comment: `border: 0px solid black`? Why not just `border: none`?  Also, `0` is unitless, so _at least_ change it to `border: 0 solid black`

Comment: I just fixed it on edge. No more line between it.

Comment: I FIXED IT!! Just check it in edge.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Microsoft Edge, this is because it's an Edge browser glitch.  You will need to edit this so that it renders in MS Edge or just bear with it right now. Try placing space between the navbar items

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19643803)

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam I am the author.

Answer (score 0):

I could replicate your problem. it is not a border, but actually two semi-transparent white backgrounds overlap in Ms Edge and creates a bolder white line. you can add margins between items in the menu, or a better solution could be to apply `background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);` to `.Menu` instead (set transparent background for menu items and keep the transition to white background on hover).